# Anyone with Quickbooks API experience? I am attempting to mark a journal entry as paid

Tags: api, quickbooks, accounting, retool

As the question states, I have a journal entry in Quickbooks for an amount of $10 total credit. I am attempting to mark this journal entry as paid for a customer without charging any sort of credit card.

I simply want to mark the journal entry as paid similar to the "receive a payment" button in Quickbooks' customer screen. I also have the ID of the journal entry but the API docs are very confusing.

The Quickbooks docs mention "linked transactions" for their API here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/workflows/manage-linked-transactions

I am making all of my API calls through Retool.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have wrong expectations from Journal Entry.

In order to create same impact as of Receive Payment using manual journals you need to push another set of journal entry to quickbooks which will balance out the chart of accounts. for reference of debits and credit of journal entry, you shall try to manually do receive payment and check the General Ledger report to see the debits and credits.

here is the Correct API documentation for Journal entry for doing CRUD operations. https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/journalentry#the-journalentry-object

Comment: The journal entry is created and balanced. I have two entries of $5 as separate debits. The issue is not with the journal entry API it is with the payment API. The link I referenced in my original post is supposed to show how this is done, but I have been struggling quite a bit to make it work.

Comment: I think you should provide some additional context about what you're trying to do here. Journal entries do not get "paid". What are you trying to accomplish by "paying" for a journal entry? What is the journal entry for?

Comment: I figured it out.